# background layout moving when soft keyboard displayed - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I've got an input popup that I'm displaying over my activities main view that has some edit boxes in it. When the popup is displayed the activities view stays dimmed in the background (like with an alert dialog).

The issue I'm having is that when the keyboard comes up the popup is ok, but activities view in the background is shifting up. That view should be paused and I wouldn't have thought it would be affected by the keyboard at all. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

I've tried adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to the activity and to the pop-up with no luck.

Here's my activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/main_bg">

<include android:id="@+id/header" layout="@layout/common_header" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
 >

<include android:id="@+id/btnBar" layout="@layout/common_button_bar" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>  

  <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/webLayout"
   android:layout_above="@+id/btnBar"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/blk"
  android:layout_margin="10dp">

   <WebView
android:id="@+id/WebView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/white"
   >


   </WebView>

  </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is my pop-up layout:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@color/light_grey" android:layout_width="wrap_content"      android:minWidth="300dp">
 <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/main_inner_layout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:layout_margin="3dp"
 >

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/enter_txt"
   android:text="Enter Cup Code Below:"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:textColor="@color/black"
   android:layout_gravity="left"
   android:typeface="sans"
   android:textSize="16dp"
   android:layout_margin="10dp"
      >
  </TextView>
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/code_layout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:background="@color/white"
  >
   <EditText
    android:text="12345"
    android:id="@+id/CodeInputOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   ></EditText>
   <EditText
    android:text="12345"
    android:id="@+id/CodeInputTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   ></EditText>
   <EditText
    android:text="12345"
    android:id="@+id/CodeInputThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       ></EditText>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/btn_layout_top"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:background="@color/white"
  >
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/AccountBtn"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="My Account"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="ClickHandler"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
   ></Button>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/SubmitBtn"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="ClickHandler"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
   ></Button>

  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/btn_layout_bottom"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:background="@color/white"
  >
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/RewardsBtn"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Rewards"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="ClickHandler"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
       ></Button>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/CancelBtn"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="ClickHandler"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
   ></Button>
   </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: When the system displays the Soft Keyboard, it actually adjusts the view origin of your activity!  Not much can be done about that, you must be aware of it in your drawing code.
The Soft Keyboard is actually managed by an external service, which manipulates the activity it is called from.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

for the activity.

Comment: Raj, this is fundamentally wrong.
The documentation says multiple values in either group (adjust or state group) can have undefined results.

Ref: [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft]