# how to avoid main window layout being scrolled when soft keyboard is opened?

Tags: android

I have a main activity which has RelativeLaoyout @ root and many other views including a GridView with 2 columns.
Now, clicking on one of the buttons opens a dialog which has an EditText in it.
When user taps in the EditText the whole RelativeLayout of the main activity is pushed upwards.

I have tried almost all of the solutions I could find on stackoverflow and various other forums but none has worked for me!

Things I have tried so far

1. Set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
   I also tried adjustNothing and adjustPan but nothing worked
2. Set android:isScrollContainer="false" for the GridView
   I also tried setting it to true. But that didn't help either.

This issue is really bugging me very bad. Please someone help!

**EDIT**
Found a duplicate but that too is un-answered!
[background layout moving when soft keyboard displayed - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783318/background-layout-moving-when-soft-keyboard-displayed-android)

Comment: have you tried:  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: Yes I did, that too did not help...
Anyway, according to the documentation adjustPan is used when you want to scroll the things and my requirement is exactly the opposite of it.

Comment: **An interesting update:**
I am facing this issue ONLY on kindle fire. It works fine on all other Android phones and tablets including kindle fire HD.
Exactly same code works on all devices except Kindle Fire.

Also, when I rotate the device to landscape mode and then rotate it back to portrait mode, then it works fine i.e. then it doesn't push the background layout upwards.

Can anybody help in understanding what must be happening between these orientation changes.
Btw, my activity has two different layouts for portrait and landscape modes.

Answer (score 0):

how adjust pan will work it just push ur edit text not ur whole background if ur edit text is in b/w the height of keyboard that comes up to the screen, the adjust pan just lift the edit text not the whole background screen and if ur edit text is above from the height of keyboard then no change will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Fullscreen theme? 
@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.FullScreen

If so, try changing it to:
@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar

It seems that in HoneyComb version and above the full screen theme setting overrides the windowSoftInputMode adjustResize or adjustPan settings.