# How to fix EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [background layout moving when soft keyboard displayed - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783318/background-layout-moving-when-soft-keyboard-displayed-android)

I have a layout file that contains severals views and EditText:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/connect"
            android:id="@+id/btnConnect" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spServers"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnConnect" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnConnect"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnConnect" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnType" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnConnect"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnConnect" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnConnect" android:textOff="@string/text"
            android:textOn="@string/grid" />
    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:id="@+id/spDataBases" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnConnect"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnConnect"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnType" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spServers"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check"
            android:id="@+id/btnCheck" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spServers" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/run"
            android:id="@+id/btnRun" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnCheck" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnCheck"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnLoad"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/load"
            android:id="@+id/btnLoad" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnConnect"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnCheck"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSQL" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spServers" android:layout_below="@+id/btnType"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnConnect" android:layout_above="@+id/btnCheck"
            android:gravity="left|top" android:singleLine="false" android:textAlignment="gravity"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But when I'm trying to type something, I'm getting this problem:

[image: I'm trying to type something]

Help me please to fix this. I don't wanna change the screen position on the layout, when I'm typing some text. It's moving up when user trying to type something.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @MrZander I wanna fix it. I don't wanna change the screen position on the layout, when I'm typing some text.

Comment: So, it is moving up when you try to type?  Post your full xml layout.

Comment: @MrZander yes! One moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to tell Android to not resize your layout when the keyboard is brought up, making sure that what you're typing is visible. (Docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Add the following to your apps' manifest: (in the relevant activity instead of the dummy one below)

```
<activity android:name="Activity"
  ..
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  ..
</activity>
```

It's unclear to me if your issue is happening when you click on the EditText and the keyboard comes up, or if it only happens once you start typing? My answer will probably not help if the latter is the case. I'm also unsure if "adjustPan" is desirable behaviour, but it's worth a shot! It could also be a good idea to put your entire RelativeLayout in a ScrollView.